# Read QByteArray setting written by QSetting within different Qt version.

Tags: qt, serialization, qt4, qsettings, qbytearray

**QByteArray** is serialized in different formats on the file system if the different version of Qt library is used (say 4.5.2 against 4.7.1).
I use the **QSettings** in my application to store the some binary data in the `.ini` file. Now application is migrated to Qt 4.7.1 and if updated version of app reads (using the **QSettings** value method) the resulted **QByteArray** is not equal to the serialized by previous version of app.

Possible solution:

- maintain the version of Qt used by app (I store the app version in the settings)
- implement the own format for **QSettings** (wrapper for ini format) with own *ReadFunc* and *WriteFunc*.
- read/write **QByteArray** settings using the **QDataStream** within *setVersion* using the maintained Qt version.

Any more simple solutions?

Comment: Hard coding a version in QDataStream seems pretty simple. It's certainly simpler than the first two options.

Comment: If it's purely the Qt version that is changing I would go for Qt's [own versioning](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qdatastream.html#versioning), as I think your last option suggests.

Answer (score 2):

QDataStream's setVersion is the simplest and quickest way.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#setVersion

and for future reference the Qt5 version:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdatastream.html#setVersion